# HTML Page - Header & Footer - Redundancy

Tags: html, css

I am creating a HTML/CSS page which has 4 link,

```
Home.html
Details.html
ContactMe.html
AboutUs.html
```

I want to keep this as Header in all the HTML pages associated.

Also the Page has a Footer which contains the a tagline sentence.

How do I avoid Coding the Header and Footer in all the HTML pages.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a server-side scripting language like PHP. :)

Comment: In php you simply can dynamicly load everything, and always include a different file with a footer and header.

Comment: can you provide an ex?

Answer (score 0):

see : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp
there are examples of simple PHP scripting

Answer (score 0):

if you can use PHP (i recommend) then you can simply include your header file:

eg. index.php:

```
<html> 
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
       <header>
          <? include('header.html'); ?>
       </header>
   </body>
</html>
```

If you have to strictly use HTML then you can load html content with jQuery

eg. index.html:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
        <script> 
            $(function(){
                $("header").load("header.html");
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body> 
        <header></header>
    </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:

In header.html you can have your menu as ul list

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Details.html">Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="ContactMe.html">Contact Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What should be content of header.html if I wanted to Display "Header ABC". Please provide that. Thanks!

Comment: @jcvd86: What do you mean by "Header ABC"? if you mean text only, then the header.html will content only "Header ABC" text. that's it. i would say in header.html you should create some <ul> list with you menu. That's what you need, right?

Comment: @jcvd86, see my update. hope it helps and you will accept some of the answers. Cheers

Comment: This one is not working. I am not able to see the content within header.html

Comment: @jcvd86 It works, try to find the error on your side.
The jQuery solution you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/PeterA/f7wqcuta/